# Installing package why is rpm and yum used here - why not just one?

Tags: yum, rpm

I am attempting to install VLC media player on my new Fedora 20 machine.
On the VLC website it states that you could install it usign the following commands (which i still did not try) as I want to know exactly what they do

```
 $> su -
    #> rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
    #> yum install vlc
    #> yum install mozilla-vlc (optional)
```

Now here are my questions:

```
rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

has the arguments i (install) v (verbose) h (hash) so this basically installs the rpm to the system correct ? Then why use yum after that ?

Also if yum does have vlc in its repo then when I go like this

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ yum list *vlc*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

why isnt anything listed ?

Also when it is installed how would i know what command should I run to launch the app ?

This makes me think that the rpm command simply adds the vlc rpm to the yum repo and then we do a yum to do the install ? I am a bit confused here and any help explaining this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> "rpm command simply adds the vlc rpm to the yum repo"...

Close. I think the package installed using `rpm` adds the [RPM Fusion repository](http://rpmfusion.org/), after which `yum` can install packages from that repository. Obviously, the first package itself could not be installed via `yum`, since it is not present in the repositories currently configured for `yum`. So it had to be manually downloaded and installed.

`vlc` is available in the RPM Fusion repository (but not in the official repositories for Fedora, I presume), so unless you add this repository, `yum list` won't show anything for `vlc`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Also could you tell me how can we determine the name of the file to run to use the application ? Normally in windows we would look for an executable in the folder of the installed app. what would the linux approach be here after the app is installed ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/104055/2072269) to  see which files are installed by the package. The files to run would be in `/usr/bin`. You can also try something like `which vlc` or `locate vlc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$> su -
    #> rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
    #> yum install vlc
    #> yum install mozilla-vlc (optional)
```

**Explanation**

`rpm -ivh`

- Install
- Verbose
- Show Hash

This installs the package showing a rotating hash mark until the install finishes.  RPM has no dependency checking.  Using `yum` adds the package to the yum repository and rechecks the dependencies.  As muru states, using `yum list` fails, as the repository doesn't exist in your repo list.  This is also the reason you must use the Fully Qualified Link when using `rpm`.